# If you overwrite a field in a subclass of a class, the subclass has two fields with the same name(and different type)?

Tags: java, subclassing, jls

I have 3 classes:

```
public class Alpha {
    public Number number;
}

public class Beta extends Alpha {
    public String number;
}

public class Gama extends Beta {
    public int number;
}
```

Why does the following code compile? And, why does the test pass without any runtime errors?

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final Beta a = new Gama();
    a.number = "its a string";
    ((Alpha) a).number = 13;
    ((Gama) a).number = 42;

    assertEquals("its a string", a.number);
    assertEquals(13, ((Alpha) a).number);
    assertEquals(42, ((Gama) a).number);
}
```

Comment: And? it works so. If you need to override, you should use setter/getter methods. Public field is nearly always bad idea.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Member variables cannot be overridden like methods. The `number` variables in your classes `Beta` and `Gama` are **hiding** (not overriding) the member variable `number` of the superclass.

By casting you can access the hidden member in the superclass.

Comment: See in The Java™ Tutorials [Hiding Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html)

Answer (score 59):

Fields can't be *overridden*; they're not accessed polymorphically in the first place - you're just declaring a new field in each case.

It compiles because in each case the compile-time type of the expression is enough to determine *which* field called `number` you mean.

In real-world programming, you would avoid this by two means:

- Common-sense: shadowing fields makes your code harder to read, so just don't do it
- Visibility: if you make all your fields private, subclasses won't know about them anyway

Answer (score 4):

**Java Hiding a field**

When successor has a **field** with the same **name** as a superclass's field it is called - **Hiding a field**

Java's field does not support polymorphism and does not take a field's type into account

```
class A {
    String field = "A: field";

    String foo() {
        return "A: foo()";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    //B's field hides A's field
    String field = "B: field";

    String foo() {
        return "B: foo()";
    }
}

@Test
public void testPoly() {
    A a = new A();
    assertEquals("A: field", a.field);
    assertEquals("A: foo()", a.foo());

    B b = new B();
    assertEquals("B: field", b.field);
    assertEquals("B: foo()", b.foo());

    //B cast to A
    assertEquals("A: field", ((A)b).field);  //<--
    assertEquals("B: foo()", ((A)b).foo());
}
```

[[Swift override property]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61374973/4770877)

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can use getter methods:

```
class A {
    private String field = "A: field";

    String getField() {
        return field;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private String field = "B: field";

    @Override        
    String getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```