# Multi-level Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I am having following classes

```
public class InheritTest{
    Parent p = new Child();
    Child c = (Child)p;
    void someMethod(){
        System.out.println(p.getX()+" "+c.getX());
    }
    public static void main (String [] args){
        InheritTest it = new InheritTest();
        it.someMethod();
    }

    class Child extends Parent{
         int x = 1;
        int getX(){
            return this.x;
        }
    }

}
```

And

```
public class Parent{
    int x = 0;
    int getX(){
        return x;
    }
}
```

When I call, p.getX() and c.getX(), it prints 1 & 1

but when I call p.x and c.x, it prints 0 & 1

how this multi-level inheritance works ?  Please help me understand this.

Comment: does your code even compile? this line looks odd  Parent p = new Child(); and after that you cast p to child type ?

Comment: yes, compiled and gave answer as mention in last lines of my question

Comment: can you at least explian these lines? Parent p = new Child();
    Child c = (Child)p;

Answer (score 1):

- In the line `Parent p = new Child();` you create `p` as a reference to an object of type `Child`
- Then you create `c` as a second reference to the **same** object

The object is the object. It is what it is. It is a `Child`.

A reference has a type, and an object has a type. They are not the same thing. They do have to be compatible.

- The type of `p` is `Parent`
- The type of `c` is `Child`
- The type of the object is `Child`, regardless of which reference (`p` or `c`) you are using

---

With regard to the different in behaviour overriding between a method and a field, see:

- [If you overwrite a field in a subclass of a class, the subclass has two fields with the same name(and different type)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414990/if-you-override-a-field-in-a-subclass-of-a-class-the-subclass-has-two-fields-wi)

Comment: would yu please explain why the op ended up with those output?

Comment: Overriding a field and a method has different behaviour. I added a link to another stackoverflow to the answer.