# Override a weak var property?

Tags: swift, overriding, var, weak

I have a class with a `weak var`,

for example :

```
class Foo {

    weak var myVar : UILabel!
}
```

If a build a subclass, can I override the property without the weak key?

I tried with the following code but I received :

```
class Foo2 : Foo{
    override var myVar : UILabel!
}
```

> "Cannot override with a stored property" error.

If it's possible to do, how can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding a stored property in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691935/overriding-a-stored-property-in-swift)

Comment: You can override an inherited instance or type property to provide your own custom getter and setter for that property, or to add property observers to enable the overriding property to observe when the underlying property value changes.

Comment: How to do this? I receveid the error

Comment: @DomenicoTaffuri Check the link added by pckill