# How to override the lazy load dataArr by swift in the new swift file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am learning `Swift`.
I create the first swift file in my iOS APP project.
The swift file is a subclass. The swift father class is ao objective-c class.
`In the objective-c file.m, I use a lazy array;`

like this:

```
- (NSArray *)dataArr{
    if(_dataArr == nil){
            NSDictionary *dic1 = @{@"title":@"dog1",
                       @"message":@"the dog1"
};
NSDictionary *dic2 = @{@"title":@"dog2",
                       @"message":@"the dog2"
};
NSDictionary *dic3 = @{@"title":@"dog3",
                       @"message":@"the dog3"
};
         _dataArr = @[dic1, dic2, dic3];
    }
    return _dataArr;
}
```

In the OC file, I use the `dataArr` to set the tableView contents.

Due to my new swift file is like the OC father file, except the array content.

I want the override the array to make the swift file table view show the new content.

My swift file code like this:

```
class testSwift: theOCFatherClass {

   override func viewDidLoad() {

          let dic1:Dictionary = ["title":"dog1",
                                      "message":"the dog1"
                                      ];
              let dic2:Dictionary = ["title":"dog2",
                                      "message":"the dog2"
                                      ];
              let dic3:Dictionary = ["title":"dog3",
       "message":"the dog3"]

       func getdataArray() -> Array<Any>{
                return [dic1, dic2, dic3]
              }

       var dataArr = getdataArray()

       super.viewDidLoad()
   }
}
```

I click into the swift page on my iPhone, the content of the swift file is my OC array.

My question is how to override the  `dataArr` by swift in the new swift file.

If you will, please write a good example.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26691935/overriding-a-stored-property-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can override a lazy Objective-C property like

```
@property (readonly, nonnull) NSArray<NSDictionary<NSString*,NSString*> *> *dataArr;
```

only with a computed property in Swift

```
class TestSwift: theOCFatherClass { 

    lazy var swiftDataArray = [["title":"cat1", "message":"the cat1"], ["title":"cat2", "message":"the cat2"], ["title":"cat3", "message":"the cat3"]]

    override var dataArr : [[String:String]] {
       return swiftDataArray
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() { ... }

}
```