# subclass object accessing superclass hidden variable

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a subclass object. Can I access a hidden variable of the superclass without using the super keyword. ?? Actually, I found a technique.. Its working but I don't understand the conceptual reason behind it.

```
class A {
    public int a = 5; 
    private int c = 6; 

    void superclass() {
        System.out.println("Super class" + " " + "value of a is " + a);
        System.out.println("Super class" + " " + "value of c is " + c);
    }
}

class B extends A {
   int b = 7;
   int a = 8; 

   void subclass() {
       System.out.println("Sub class" + " " + "value of b is " + b);
       System.out.println("Sub class" + " " + "value of a is " + a);
   }
}

class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       A a1 = new A();
       B b1 = new B();

       b1.superclass();
   }
}
```

In the above code, if `b1` is a object of class B.I have called a superclass method named `superclass()`; Now the output is `a=5`. But my argument is why can't it be `a=8` ? `a=5` is hidden and to access it, we have to use super keyword. But here without super key word I am getting `a=5`. How can it be possible?

Comment: Does your code compile? I am voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: I don't think it does. He copied two lines by mistake I feel. I have edited the question, it will be more readable once it's approved. @ChetanKinger, sidenote, I don't feel this is off-topic.

Comment: @AnindyaDutta The code does not compile. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @ChetanKinger It does now :)

Comment: @AnindyaDutta You just encouraged more people to be lazy and create more mess on this wonderful site ;).

Comment: @ChetanKinger  : Actually, I am a new user. I don't feel like adding a simple doubt most make this site mess. This site is not only for professionals but also for beginners.

Answer (score 2):

Fields are not overriden.

So even though `B` defines an `int` named 'a' and `A` defines the same `int` with the same name does not mean they are the same field.

What is seen here is [Encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29). Accessing fields through a controlled method (here, `superclass()`). When you call `superclass`, it looks for the field `a`, which is within its own class. The class `A` knows nothing about the field `a` in `B`, not even that it exists.

There is also another SnackOverflow question here on this: [If you override a field in a subclass of a class, the subclass has two fields with the same name(and different type)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414990/if-you-override-a-field-in-a-subclass-of-a-class-the-subclass-has-two-fields-wi)

Comment: Does this mean that a object of class B does have the fields of private variable of parent class ?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, when you call a method of the superclass, irrespective of which class `extends` it, it will print the value that is in the `class`. This is because the superclass does not know which (or how many classes) extend it. That is the basic OOP principle of `encapsulation`.

Comment: Java doesn't have `functions`.

Comment: `methods`. Sorry for the mistake.