# How does Java's inheritance constructor work?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, extends

Why the output is:

```
> B.foo(): bar = null 
> B.foo(): bar = B.bar 
>a.bar = A.bar 
>B.foo(): bar =B.bar
```

BUT not:

> ```
> > B.foo(): bar = null 
> > A.foo(): bar = A.bar 
> >a.bar = A.bar 
> >B.foo(): bar =B.bar
> ```

1) B extends A so doesn't it suppose call to A's class? 2)  Why by a.bar class A is called and not B ? 3)May you explain the output?
code:

```
public class A {
    String bar= "A.bar";
    A() { foo(); }
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A.foo(): bar = "+ bar);
    }
}
public class B extends A {
    String bar= "B.bar";
    B() { foo(); }
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("B.foo(): bar = "+ bar);
    }
}
public class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a= newB();
        System.out.println("a.bar = "+ a.bar);
        a.foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code. It won't compile as is.

Comment: why by line:"A a=new B();" the output has two lines?

Comment: Methods can be overriden, fields cannot be. [This question might help explain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414990/if-you-override-a-field-in-a-subclass-of-a-class-the-subclass-has-two-fields-wi) why the two fields with the same name aren't treated the same as two methods with the same signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When instantiating a class that has inheritance, the parent's constructor is invoked first.

So in this case, the constructor for `A` is invoked first.  The constructor for `B` is invoked second.

```
B.foo(): bar = null  // output from B.foo() invoked from A's constructor
B.foo(): bar = B.bar // output from B.foo() invoked from B's constructor
```

In both cases, the constructors invoke `foo()`.  Regardless of the fact that foo() is defined in both classes, because `foo()`'s invocation is polymorphic, and the instance being created is of type `B`, in ***both*** constructor invocations, it's `B`'s `foo()` method that is called.  That's why both output lines start with `B.foo(): bar = ...`.

And finally, the reason why the first line prints `= null` instead of `B.bar` is because it is trying to print the value of the `bar` variable inside the `B` class ***before*** the `B` class has even started initializing its fields, so the value is still `null`.  `B`'s `bar` variable only gets initialized ***after*** `A`'s constructor has finished its work.

This is why you never want to invoke overrideable methods inside a class constructor.  It leads to unexpected behavior like this where you can inadvertently read uninitialized fields. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors) explains this in more detail.