# Wondering about the output of the following Java program

Tags: java, subclass, extends, superclass, super

I am dealing with some past exam papers and here I am not sure of the output. I think I am not clear about extends and super.

```
public class Superclass{
    public boolean aVariable;

    public void aMethod(){
        aVariable = true;
    }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    public boolean aVariable;

    public void aMethod() {
      aVariable = false;
      super.aMethod();
      System.out.println(aVariable);
      System.out.println(super.aVariable);
    }
}
```

I think that the second output would be true since it would refer to the super class and it is an object. However, I am not sure of the first output. Would it be just a value and print false or it is also an object?

Comment: Why dont you compile and run it? Add a main method to Subclass which calls aMethod() and see what the output is?

Comment: err i also need a explanation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output will be:

```
false
true
```

Because in your `Subclass` `aVariable` is `false` by default (so assignation `aVariable = false;` is needless). Read more about [Primitive Data Types default values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).
And  in `Superclass` you initialize `aVariable` as `true` by invoking the superclass' method using the keyword **super**: `super.aMethod();`. Read more about [Accessing Superclass Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Take a look on [demo](http://ideone.com/hLAS0i).

Comment: Thx for your demo but when I paste it to eclipse it just don't work and assumed that I do not have a main method and run main method from other  classes as before

Comment: so, invoking super.aMethod(); doesn't change aVariable value to true on SubClass ?

Comment: Press right click on your class name in the **Project Explorer** and select **Run As... → Java Application**.

Comment: @James: Yes you had made public class as Superclass but main method is declared on SubClass. If you remove public keyword on SuperClass, it should work

Comment: @ankitjava `super.aMethod();` it changes. I meant that condition `aVariable = false;` is needless here.

Comment: so what effect does the first super.aMethod() in the subclass has?

Comment: `super.aMethod();` calls the `aMethod()` of the **Superclass**, where you assign its `aVariable` to true. That's why the second line of output if `true`. If you remove this line the output will be `false false`.

Answer (score 1):

Since they're both scoped to their own class block, having them with the same name doesn't matter. As it looks like now, you set aVariable to false, the call to the super doesn't change that, except for creating another variable (new reference) with the same name and sets it to true. So the expected output would be

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 1):

Output will be:

```
false
true
```

`super.aMethod()` will execute making `aVariable = true` of SuperClass

`aVariable` of SubClass will remain `false`.

Comment: but why does the super.aMethod() before the println does not have an effect on aVariable?

Comment: as being explained above, super.aMethod() changes value of aVariable for SuperClass while value of aVariable for SubClass remains same

Answer (score 0):

I conducted scientific experiment (copy-pasted and ran) and it prints
false
true

More here:

[If you overwrite a field in a subclass of a class, the subclass has two fields with the same name(and different type)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414990/if-you-overwrite-a-field-in-a-subclass-of-a-class-the-subclass-has-two-fields-w)