# Why this is happening in Java?

Tags: java

I have been knowing java for a while still sometime i think, i lack few basic concepts. Here is a code which i am trying to run:

```
   class A{
    int x =10;
    void al(){
        System.out.println("From a");
    }
}
class B extends A{
    int x = 20;
    void al(){
        System.out.println("From b");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        A obj = new B();
        B obj1 = new B();
        A obj2 = new A();
        System.out.println(obj.x);
        obj.al();
        System.out.println(obj1.x);
        System.out.println(obj2.x);
    }
}
```

and here is the output:

```
  10
From b
20
10
```

When i try to call the function **al** it calles the function in **B** class. Simple overriding is happening over here. Obj tries to find first in base class then in super class.
Now, when i try to access the "X" by object **obj** it displays "10".
Why it is not displaying "20" ?

Comment: because A.x and B.x are different beasts since B **redeclares** x

Comment: you need to refer concepts like upcasting and downcasting in inheritence thats what happening here

Comment: There exists no property overriding in Java

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9414990

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question, specifically, seems to be "why does `System.out.println(obj.x);` print 10 and not 20?"

`obj` is declared as an `A`, and so `obj.x` will always resolve to the field `x` that exists within `A`. There is no [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) for fields.

Ultimately, your problem is that there is no field overriding in Java. The field in the super class just gets [hidden](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html). When you declare

```
class A {
    int x = 10;
}
class B extends A{
    int x = 20;
}
```

and instantiate a `B`, the object that you get back actually contains **two** integers. The fact that they have the same name is basically incidental and just makes it slightly harder to refer to them independently, which is usually why you should just choose different names.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override attributes as you can override methods. "obj" is declared as an object of type A, although the instance is of type B. A.x and B.x are two distincts attributes and not related by any means, although A.al() is overriden by B.al().

Answer (score 1):

Instance `variables` ***cannot*** be overridden. They are resolved at *compile time* as opposed to *instance methods*.