# How do I override an inherited protected attribute from a parent class?

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm coming up with a set of Java classes for templating.

I have an abstract template:

```
package Test;

public class Abstract {
    protected String template = "ABSTRACT TEMPLATE";
    public Abstract() {

    }

    public void Render() {
        System.out.println("FROM ABSTRACT RENDER:");
        System.out.println(this.template);
    }
}
```

And an actual one:

```
package Test;

public class Actual extends Abstract {
    protected String template = "ACTUAL TEMPLATE";
    public Actual() {
        super();
        System.out.println("FROM ACTUAL CONSTRUCTOR:");
        System.out.println(this.template);
    }

    public void Test() {
        System.out.println("FROM ACTUAL TEST:");
        System.out.println(this.template);
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble getting the extending class to reset the value of a protected attribute (in this case `template`) and letting be used by the abstract method.

This is my use case:

```
Actual actual = new Actual();
actual.Render();
actual.Test();
```

And this is my output:

```
FROM ACTUAL CONSTRUCTOR:
ACTUAL TEMPLATE
FROM ABSTRACT RENDER:
ABSTRACT TEMPLATE <--- this is the problem, why not "ACTUAL"?
FROM ACTUAL TEST:
ACTUAL TEMPLATE
```

How do I override that value from the child class? If I don't set it to anything, calling the abstract method will always say the attribute is null, even though it's set in the child class.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/9414990/5168011

Comment: "Variables are not polymorphic in Java; they do not override one another."

Comment: just remove the field "Actual.template".