# Java Anonymous class redefining

Tags: java, anonymous-class

This is simple java program of anonymous class where class is redefined (not interface) as anonymous class.

```
class Anonymous {
    int i = 10;
    void main() {
        System.out.println("Anonymous Main " + i);
    }

    void setI(int i) {
        System.out.println("under set");
        this.i = i;
    }

    void main2() {
        setI(30);
        System.out.println("Main 2's " + i);
    }

}

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Anonymous a = new Anonymous() {
            int i = 20;

            @Override
            void setI(int i) {
                System.out.println("Over set");
                this.i = i;
            }

            @Override
            public void main() {
                setI(0);
                System.out.println("Redefined Anonymous Main " + i);
            }
        };
        a.main();
        a.main2();
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
Over set
Redefined Anonymous Main 0
Over set
Main 2's 10
```

I have few questions:

1. In `main2`, why it has access to `i` with `10` value?
2. Why object `a` has two copies of `i`?
3. If has, then when calling `setI` why there is not two copies of `setI`?
4. Why `main2` access to redefined `setI` and not `i`?
5. What exactly is Java doing?

Comment: 1. Because it is effectively `final`. 2. One is an instance member, one is a method parameter; there is also an inherited but hidden instance member. 3. Because one overrides the other, but it has nothing to do with (2). 4. It has access to both, as you said yourself in (1). 5. Obeying the scope rules.

Comment: In the second class, you should change the name from `i` it is just confusing and doesn't really add anything.

Comment: `i` is a field, it is NOT "effectively `final`" (@user207421) - that term is (officially) only used for *local variables* and *parameters* - the cause is that `setI()` is overridden in the anon class (not to be confused with its parent: `Anonymous`) which changes the `i` field of the anon class; while `main2()` is printing the value of the `i` field from `Anonymous` (the parent class)

Comment: The important thing to remember is that, **as opposed to methods, *fields are never overridden***. This answers all 5 of the questions, by the way. Within `main2`, the `i` is pointing to `Anonymous`'s `i`, while `setI` is pointing to `Anonymous$1`'s `setI`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start [from reading this part of Oracle guides](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html). Then I hope it will all be a bit more transparent for you. The thing you should understand is that `i` in the parent and `i` in the child [are not the same at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414990/if-you-overwrite-a-field-in-a-subclass-of-a-class-the-subclass-has-two-fields-w).

So, regarding your questions:

1. main2() is not overridden, therefore JIT will use the parent's version of the method using its visibility context of course. The parent does not know about the child's variable `i`. Only the child knows that it has hidden the parent field. Therefore your parent prints it's `i` (not the same as child's `i`), but the `setI` is overridden, and thus `setI` sets the value of the child's `i`.
2. Because this is how Java works :) Provided link already
3. Because the method in the child overrides the one in the parent. [It is not hiding in this case, it is true polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html).
4. Becuase you are invoking `main2()` on object that has overridden `setI`. Therefore it invokes overridden version of `setI`. Again - when `i` is modified inside `main2`, it is not the same `i` as in the child, and `main2()` in parent has no access to child's `i`.
5. Just obeying the JLS :) This is expected behavior, I hope now you understand why.

Comment: BTW the first link is not a link to the JLS, but to the tutorials (the *Java Language Specification* can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html))

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have adjusted answer a bit, thanks!